# push flow relabel algorithm

Tags: algorithm, graph-algorithm, max-flow

A valid labelling of the vertices in V wrt. a preflow x is a function d[.] : V -> Z satisfying:

d[s] = n ^ d[t] = 0

for all (v,w) belong to E : d[v] <= d[w] + 1

supposed we have 4 verticies including (s and t)

then we have d[s] = 4

according to valid labeling we should have d[v] <= d[w]+1, but for edges which are coming from 's', it is not
valid because 4 <= 1 is false. Is this logic is not only source?

Am I understading it right? Please correct me.

Thanks for your time and help

Answer (score 1):

Your definition of a valid labelling is close, but not quite correct.

You claim that d[v] <= d[w] + 1 for all (v,w) belonging to E.

However, this actually only needs to be true for all (v,w) belonging to R, where R is a **residual** edge.

A residual edge is an edge where the current flow is less than the capacity on the edge.

There is a good explanation at [topcoder](http://community.topcoder.com/tc?module=Static&d1=tutorials&d2=maxflowPushRelabel).

Consider this diagram:

[image: Example flow]

In the labels on the edges (such as 2/3) the first number gives the current flow, and the second number gives the capacity of the edge.

The numbers on the nodes give the height function d for each node.

The green edges are the residual edges because they have spare capacity.

So to check the height constraint we only need to check the S->A edge, and the B->T edge.

Comment: sorry @Peter diagram is missing

Comment: Perhaps you have the imgur domain blocked?  Have a look at the topcoder site, it has much better diagrams than my attempt in any case.